# Custom field to category

Tags: php, function, categories

I use to see this script to auto fields to a category

```
function wpse_248054(){

    $custom_field_name = 'Genre';

    $posts = new WP_Query(
        array(
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'post_type'=> 'post',
        )   
    );

    foreach($posts->posts as $post){

        $meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Genre', true);

        if(! empty( $meta )){
            $term_id = wp_create_category($meta, 3); // 2nd argument, parent id (optional)

            $new_post_cat = wp_set_post_terms( $post->ID, $term_id, 'category', true );

        }
    }
}

add_action('admin_init', 'wpse_248054');
```

The meta key is `Genre`.

But contains comma separator (example: Short, Western, Drama)

And this script creates a category `Short, Western, Drama` altogether, who can I adjust this?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ? Create 3 new category ?

Comment: exactly, custom field can have multiple values with comma separator, i need this script assuming this value with categories separator comma

Comment: Improve readability